# How do I Add A Background Image to my Navigation Bar?

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble adding an image to navigation bar. 
I have tried adding

```
#header, #nav {
background-image: url("https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/white-marble-texture-background_38679-514.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg") repeat;
}
```

HTML:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
  </ul>
</nav>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
  #header #nav { 
  background-image: url(https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/white-marble-texture-background_38679-514.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg);
  background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

I want the Navigation bar to have a marble background

Comment: Your code is looking for ids not elements. # is an id selector. It should just be `header nav {} `

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try. Also I changed your background-image style to just background so that you could include the "repeat" shorthand property.
html

```
<header>
    <nav>
        <ul></ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

css

```
    header, nav {
    background: url("https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/white-marble-texture-background_38679-514.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg") repeat;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you are assigning css properties to elements with ids header and nav. if this is the case add the id attribute to each element.

Second the background-image property only allows you to set a background image but you want your image to repeat, instead use `background`

And Finally background images need the element to have a defined height or content in order to be visible

Here is how the final code should look:

```css
#header, #nav 
{
    background: url("https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/white-marble-texture-background_38679-514.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg") repeat;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<header id="header"> 
  <nav id="nav">
    <ul></ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```